# Совместная работа Spring Security и JUnit5

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, junit

У меня есть готовое REST приложение на Spring Boot с использованием Spring Security.
Ручное тестирование показывает что приложение работает корректно. Теперь я хочу покрыть его автоматическими тестами на JUnit5 но сталкиваюсь с NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.
Мой класс User:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User extends BaseEntity{

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private boolean active;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "vote_id")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Vote vote;

    public User(Long id, String username, String password, String firstName, String lastName, Role role, boolean active) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.role = role;
        this.active = active;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id='" + getId() + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", role=" + role +
                ", active=" + active +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Security Config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public SecurityConfig(@Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl") UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/users").permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }

    @Bean
    protected PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    protected DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider(){
        DaoAuthenticationProvider daoAuthenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        daoAuthenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return daoAuthenticationProvider;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(daoAuthenticationProvider());
    }
}
```

Security User:

```
public class SecurityUser implements UserDetails {

    private final String username;
    private final String password;
    private final List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities;
    private final boolean isActive;

    public SecurityUser(String username, String password, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities, boolean isActive) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.isActive = isActive;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }

    public static UserDetails fromUser(User user) {
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.isActive(),
                user.isActive(),
                user.isActive(),
                user.isActive(),
                user.getRole().getAuthorities()
        );
    }
}
```

UserDetailsServiseImpl:

```
@Service("userDetailsServiceImpl")
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username).orElseThrow(() ->
                new UsernameNotFoundException("Username: " + username + " not found"));
        return SecurityUser.fromUser(user);
    }
}
```

Так же есть классы хранящие роли и права доступа для этих ролей:

```
public enum Role {
    ADMIN(Set.of(Permission.READ_YOUR_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER,
            Permission.READ_ANY_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER,
            Permission.CHANGE_ANY_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER,
            Permission.CHANGE_YOUR_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER,
            Permission.VOTE,
            Permission.READ_ENTRIES_ABOUT_EVERYTHING,
            Permission.CHANGE_ENTRIES_ABOUT_EVERYTHING)),
    USER(Set.of(Permission.READ_YOUR_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER,
            Permission.CHANGE_YOUR_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER,
            Permission.VOTE,
            Permission.READ_ENTRIES_ABOUT_EVERYTHING));

    private final Set<Permission> permissions;

    Role(Set<Permission> permissions) {
        this.permissions = permissions;
    }

    public Set<Permission> getPermissions() {
        return permissions;
    }

    public Set<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getPermissions().stream()
                .map(permission -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(permission.getPermission()))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}

public enum Permission {
    READ_YOUR_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER("users:read your entries"),
    READ_ANY_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER("users:read any entries"),
    CHANGE_YOUR_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER("users:change your entries"),
    CHANGE_ANY_ENTRIES_ABOUT_USER("users:change any entries"),
    VOTE("users:vote"),
    READ_ENTRIES_ABOUT_EVERYTHING("everything:read entries"),
    CHANGE_ENTRIES_ABOUT_EVERYTHING("everything:change entries");

    private final String permission;

    Permission(String permission) {
        this.permission = permission;
    }

    public String getPermission() {
        return permission;
    }
}
```

Теперь я хочу написать тесты для этого контроллера:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/admin/users")
public class AdminRestController {
    private final UserService userService;

    public AdminRestController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users:read any entries')")
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDto>> getAll() {
        List<UserDto> allUsers = userService.findAll().stream()
                .map(UserDto::fromUser)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(allUsers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @GetMapping("/by-id/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users:read any entries')")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        User user = userService.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(UserDto.fromUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @GetMapping("/by-username/{username}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users:read any entries')")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> getByUsername(@PathVariable String username) {
        User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
        if (user == null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(UserDto.fromUser(user), HttpStatus.OK);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users:change any entries')")
    public ResponseEntity<UserDto> update(@RequestBody User user) {
        User result = userService.update(user);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(UserDto.fromUser(result), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    @PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('users:change any entries')")
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        userService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

Для этого я написал такой класс:

```
@WebMvcTest(AdminRestController.class)
public class AdminRestControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

//    @Autowired
//    @Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")
//    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    ObjectMapper mapper;

    @MockBean
    UserService userService;

    User user1 = new User(1L, "igor", "igor", "Igor", "Meshalkin", Role.ADMIN, true);
    User user2 = new User(2L, "ivan", "ivan", "Ivan", "Ivanov", Role.USER, true);

    @Test
//    @WithMockUser(username = "igor", password = "igor", roles = {"USER", "ADMIN"})
    public void getAll() throws Exception {
        List records = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(user1, user2));

        Mockito.when(userService.findAll()).thenReturn(records);

        mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                        .get("/api/admin/users")
                        .with(SecurityMockMvcRequestPostProcessors.user("igor").roles("ADMIN"))
                        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

Как видно из закомментированного кода я пытался получить бин UserDetailsService при помощи @Autovired, а так же разными способами указать тестового юзера. Но каждый раз я получаю такой стектрейс:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in com.igormeshalkin.restaurant_vote.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration.

2022-05-24 13:33:41.000 ERROR 10184 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@1c852c0f] to prepare test instance [com.igormeshalkin.restaurant_vote.rest.AdminRestControllerTest@423a0e1d]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.postProcessFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:110) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.injectFields(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:94) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(MockitoTestExecutionListener.java:61) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [C:\projects\RestaurantVote\target\classes\com\igormeshalkin\restaurant_vote\config\SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1372) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1222) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:144) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier("userDetailsServiceImpl")}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1799) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 90 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Советую почитать о том, как работает аннотация `@WebMvcTest` https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.testing.spring-boot-applications.spring-mvc-tests

Если кратко, то `@WebMvcTest` не подразумевает сканирование `@Service` классов.

Вашу проблему можно решить вот такой конструкцией, то есть добавить `@Import(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class)`

```
@WebMvcTest(AdminRestController.class)
@Import(UserDetailsServiceImpl.class)
class AdminRestControllerTest {

    ...

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    ...

}
```